# PostgreSQL - select only rows where a previous entry satisfied a condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the below details

```
+------+---------+-------+--+
| name |  Plan   | Date  |  |
+------+---------+-------+--+
| A    | free    | 3/06  |  |
| B    | paid    | 2/06  |  |
| A    | paid    | 5/06  |  |
| B    | paid    | 5/06  |  |
+------+---------+-------+--+
```

I want to find a list of people who've entered a paid plan today **but only if** their previous plan was also paid

In this case (today's current date of 5/06), I would only get B  (because A's previous pla was a free plan)

Is there any way for me to this in postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.date = current_date and plan = 'paid'
and exists (
  select 1 from test
  where 
    name = t.name and plan = 'paid'
    and date = (select max(date) from test where name = t.name and date < t.date)   
)
```

Comment: I think you need another plan = 'paid' outside of the exists or else you would get results for people who were free today and paid last time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to look at the previous row:

```
create table test (name text, plan text, date date);

insert into test values ('A', 'free', '2019-03-06'), ('B', 'paid', '2019-02-06'), ('A', 'paid', '2019-05-06'), ('B', 'paid', '2019-05-06');

select name 
FROM 
  (select name, 
          date, 
          plan = lag(plan) over (partition by name order by date) as same_as_prev
   FROM test
   WHERE plan = 'paid'
) sub
WHERE date = '2019-05-06'
AND same_as_prev = 't';
 name
------
 B
(1 row)
```

Edit: I just realized that I probably mixed up your month and day, but the idea is exactly the same

Comment: Will try this - what exactly does this statement mean? `AND same_as_prev = 't';`

Comment: The column same_as_prev is a boolean.  It's true if the previous row by that name was also paid.  The same_as_prev = 't' is just selecting the rows where this is true.